# how to always show markers in zoomable datetime charts in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

in zoomable datetime charts of highcharts , i cant set markers visibility to visible.by hover its visible but otherwise its hidden. also when i zoom in it , its still hidden. here are my codes:

```
Highcharts.chart('projecttimeline', {
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    type: 'area', 
    resetZoomButton: { 
        position: {
            align: 'left', 
            verticalAlign: 'top',  
            x: 5,
            y: 5
        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'نمودار پیشرفت پروژه در واحد زمان'
},
subtitle: {
    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
            'بر روی نمودار کلیک کنید و بکشید تا بزرگ شود' : 'با دو انگشت نمودار را بزرگ کنید'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {  
            return persianDate(new Date(this.value)).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); 
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0, max: 100 ,
    title: {
        text: 'درصد پیشرفت'
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {  
            return toPersiandigit(this.value+""); 
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
}, 
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        color : _opened.darkc,
        fillColor:Highcharts.Color(_opened.lightc).setOpacity(0.3).get('rgba'),
        marker: {
            fillColor:"#000000",
            radius: 2 
        }  
    }
},
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        var d = prgtimedate[this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )];
        return (
            '<div class="" dir="rtl" align="right">تسک: ' +d[3] +'</div>'+
            '<div class="" dir="rtl" align="right">توسط: '+ d[4] +'</div>'+
            '<div class="" dir="rtl" align="right">پیشرفت به: '+toPersiandigit(d[1]+"")+'</div>'+
            '<div class="" dir="ltr" align="right">'+
                persianDate(new Date(this.x)).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
            +'</div>'
        );
    }
},
series: [{ 
    name: 'زمان',
    data: prgtimedate 
}]
});
```

and here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVQrc.jpg).so how can i fix it ?

look it at jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mLbhcuf8/4/

Comment: Could you please prepare minimal working example of your issue? I have tried your code with fixed data and it looks ok on my side: http://jsfiddle.net/mLbhcuf8/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thank you so much , yes , you right , your codes work fine , but my codes dont work fine , please look it: http://jsfiddle.net/mLbhcuf8/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the markers to always be visible in the series options like this

```
series: [{ 
    name: 'زمان',
    data: data,
    marker:{
     enabled: true
    }
}]
```

further options for markers can be found
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Carea%3E.marker

is this what you are trying to achieve?